# couchbase cbc failed to bootstrap instance

Tags: couchbase, document, querying

**running below command**

```
cbc n1ql   'SELECT * FROM `travel-sample`'
```

**Throws exception below**

Failed to bootstrap instance. libcouchbase error: Authentication failed. You may have provided an invalid username/password combination (0x2)

I am referring to documentation located at

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.5/sdk/development-intro.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to supply a username/password to get access to use the travel-sample bucket. Try using your admin user to get started. Later, you can create a user with specific permissions on travel-sample.

If you just enter "cbc" it should dump the set of valid options, letting you find the options to use to supply the username and password.